# Get all values per table column dynamically using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all values per column dynamically and save it using JS or Jquery. I have a photo here so that you guys can visualize what I am trying to do. Please see the image.

[image: Actual Image]

Sad to say this is as far as I can go. I cant seems to get what I realy want to achieve. Just a beginner here.

```js
$(function() {

  $('#add_supplier').click(function() {

    $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#first-header').append(
      '<th colspan="2" class="supplier_name"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Supplier" style="text-align: center;"></th>'
    );

    $('#supplier_table > thead > tr#second-header').append(
      '<th>Price</th>' +
      '<th>Total</th>'
    );

    $('#supplier_table > tbody > tr').not('#totals,#tr-td-2').append(
      '<td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control price text-right" ></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control total text-right" readonly></td>'
    );

    $('#supplier_table > tbody > #totals').not('#tr-td-2').append(
      '<td class="ignore"><input class="form-control" disabled></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control grandtotal text-right" readonly=""></td>'
    );

    $('#supplier_table > tbody > #tr-td-2').append(
      '<td colspan="2" style="width: 160px;"><input style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" type="text"></td>'
    );

    //
    refresh_index();

    //
  });

  $('#add_terms').click(function() {
    var $tableBody = $('#supplier_table').find("tbody").not('#totals'),
      $trLast = $tableBody.find("tr:last"),

      $trNew = $trLast.clone();
    $trNew.find('input').val('');
    $trLast.after($trNew);

    refresh_index();
  });

  // $('#add_supplier').click();

  $('#add_item').click(function() {

    $('#supplier_table > tbody').not('#totals, #tr-td-2').append(
      // $("#supplier_table tbody tr:last").clone()
      '<tr class="tbody-tr">' +
      '<td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control " value="Monitor" readonly=""></td>' +
      '<td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="30" readonly=""></td>' +
      '<td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control price"></td>' +
      '<td><input type="text" class="form-control total for_sum-1" readonly=""></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );

    //        
    refresh_index();

    //
  });

  //
  function refresh_index() {

    $('.price').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'price-' + i);
      $(this).attr('data-num', i);
      event_handler();
    });

    $('.total').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'total-' + i);
    });

    $('.qty').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'qty-' + i);
    });

    $('.grandtotal').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'grandtotal-' + i);
    });

    $('.supplier_name').each(function(i) {
      i++;
      $(this).attr('id', 'supplier_name-' + i);
    });
  }
  refresh_index();

  //

  //
  function event_handler() {
    $('.price').unbind('keyup').bind('keyup', function() {
      var id = this.id;
      var num = id.split('-');
      var pos = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
      var qty = $('#qty-' + pos).val();
      var price = $(this).val();
      var total = parseFloat(qty) * parseFloat(price);
      if (isNaN(total)) {
        var total = 0;
      }

      $('#total-' + num[1]).text(total);
      $('#total-' + num[1]).val(total);

      var num_of_supplier_name = $('.supplier_name').length;
      sum_of_total();
    });
  }

  function sum_of_total() {
    // var sum = 0;
    // //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    // $(".total").each(function () {
    //     //add only if the value is number
    //     if (!isNaN($(this).val()) && $(this).val().length != 0) {
    //         sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    //     }
    // });
    // //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    // $("#grandtotal-"+num).val(sum);
    var totals = [];
    $('#tb').find('tr').each(function() {
      var $row = $(this);
      $row.children('td').not('.ignore').each(function(index) {
        totals[index] = totals[index] || 0;
        totals[index] += parseInt($(this).text()) || 0;
      });
    })

    $('#totals td').not('.ignore').each(function(index) {
      // $(this).text(totals[index]);
      var id = index + 1;
      $('#grandtotal-' + id).val(totals[index]);
    });

    $("#tb").on("click", "tr", function() {
      $(this).find("td").slice(0, 4).prop("contenteditable", true);
    });

    // var max = 0;
    // $('.grandtotal').each(function()
    // {
    //    $this = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    //    // console.log($this);
    //    if ($this > max) {
    //     max = $this;
    //     }
    //     // $('.grandtotal').val(max).css('background-color','yellow');
    //     // console.log('Lowest Offer : '+max);
    // });
    //  console.log('Lowest Offer : '+max);


    // var high = Math.min.apply(Math, $('.grandtotal').map(function(){
    // return $(this).val()
    // }))
    // console.log('Lowest Offer : '+high);

    var vals = $('.grandtotal').map(function() {
      return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) ? parseInt($(this).val(), 10) : null;
    }).get();

    // then find their minimum
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, vals);
    console.log(min);

    // tag any cell matching the min value
    $('.grandtotal').filter(function() {
      // return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) === min;
      if (parseInt($(this).val(), 10) === min) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "#dff0d8");
      } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
      }
    });
  }
  //
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add_supplier">Add Supplier</button>
<!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="add_item">Add Item</button> -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_terms">Add Terms</button>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="supplier_table">
  <thead>
    <tr id="first-header">
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2" class="supplier_name" id="supplier_name-1"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Supplier" style="text-align: center;"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="second-header">
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tb">

    <tr class="tbody-tr">
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Mouse" readonly=""></td>
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="10" readonly=""></td>
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control price"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control total for_sum-1" readonly=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbody-tr">
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control" value="Keyboard" readonly=""></td>
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="20" readonly=""></td>
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control price"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control total for_sum-1" readonly=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbody-tr">
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control " value="Monitor" readonly=""></td>
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control qty" value="30" readonly=""></td>
      <td class="ignore"><input type="text" class="form-control price"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control total for_sum-1" readonly=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="totals">
      <td class="ignore"></td>
      <td class="ignore"></td>
      <td class="ignore"><input class="form-control" disabled value="Grand Total : " style="text-align: right;"></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="form-control grandtotal text-right" readonly=""></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="tr-td-2">
      <td>
        <p style="width: 60px;"></p>
      </td>
      <td><input style="font-weight: bold; text-align: right;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter terms"></td>
      <!-- <td ><p style="width: 60px;"></p></td> -->
      <td colspan="2" style="width: 160px;"><input style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Actual Demo Link
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/juandela/yw91dgL3/4/)

Comment: Where are you trying to save it?

Comment: Trying to save it through ajax. I want to store per supplier column into array

Comment: I don't see any use of AJAX in the code you posted. Where would that go?

Comment: Multiple things to do here. First, you must decorate each column input with a column-id attribute, so you can know later where to put each saved value...same for columns and rows...

Let say you add a new supplier...each input added to the html should contains something like this.. cell-id="suppliername-rowname:rowvalue" so after you get the data from the ajax call, you can split the values and put the saved value were it belongs

Comment: Consider using `.off()` versus `.unbind()`.

Comment: Also you can iterate each row and specify a specific `<tr>` element within, like `$("tr td:eq(2)")`

Comment: Sad to say that's what I am supposed to do. To store per supplier column into an array. And once I get that, I can now take care on the server side.

Comment: This is the code where Im trying to store the value. 
var dtl = [];
     $('#supplier_table tbody .tbody-tr').each(function (row, tr){
       dtl [row] = {
         "price"           : $(tr).find('td:eq(2) input').val(),
         "total"           : $(tr).find('td:eq(3) input').val(),
       }
     });

Comment: I would not recommend using indexes :eq() for a simple reason. If you need to change your html, you will need to correct EVERY index reference you have.

Comment: Sorry guys just a beginner here. Can you show at least how to apply those of what you have said?